# Deleteing Nodes in XML with hyperlink using PHP and HTML

Tags: php, xml

I'm working on a PHP script that allows me to delete nodes in an XML file. I would like to have a table with the different nodes displayed underneith their parent elements `<tag>`. On the right of the table I want to have a delete link to delete the specific node `<string>` that is adjacent to the delete link. I don't want other nodes with the same values to be effected. Only one node can be deleted at a time. I have most of the code written but when I click the delete link nothing happens (other than the URL changing). Please bare with me XML and PHP together are not my strong suit.

Here is my PHP code, it calls the filename from another file via a session. I have tested that part and it works flawlessly.

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['file'])) {
    $fileName = $_SESSION['file'];
$symbols = simplexml_load_file ( $fileName );
if(isset($_GET['action'])){
  $id = $_GET['string'];
  foreach ($symbols->symbol as $symbol) {
    if ($symbol['string']==$id) {
      $dom = dom_import_simplexml($symbol);
      $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
    }
    echo $symbols->asXml();
  }
}


echo "<table border='1'>";
 foreach ($symbols->xpath(".//HighwayRoutingData") as $routingPoints){
    $tag=(string)$routingPoints->tag;
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<td>".$tag."</td>";
     echo "<td></td>";
     foreach($routingPoints->xpath(".//destinationSymbols//string") as $symbol){
     $sym = (string)$symbol;
     echo "<tr><td>{$sym}</td>";
     echo '<td><a href="delete.php?action=delete&string='.$sym.'">Delete</a></tr>';
     echo "</td>";


}

echo "</tr>";  
}
echo "</table>";
}else{
  echo "Session not set";
}
?>
```

Here is the XML files im looking to delete nodes from. Note I have used this XML example in the past for previous parts of my project. This is in no way a duplicate

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfHighwayRoutingData xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <HighwayRoutingData>
    <tag>@I80</tag>
    <destinationSymbols>
      <string>SFO</string>
      <string>OAK</string>
      <string>EMR</string>
      <string>ELC</string>
      <string>RIC</string>
      <string>SPB</string>
      <string>Q185</string>
      <string>Q456</string>
      <string>ads</string>
      <string>ads</string>
    </destinationSymbols>
  </HighwayRoutingData>
  <HighwayRoutingData>
    <tag>@SR24</tag>
    <destinationSymbols>
      <string>OAK</string>
      <string>ORI</string>
      <string>LFY</string>
      <string>WCR</string>
      <string>G151</string>
    </destinationSymbols>
  </HighwayRoutingData>
  <HighwayRoutingData>
    <tag>@US101</tag>
    <destinationSymbols>
      <string>SFO</string>
      <string>SSC</string>
      <string>MIL</string>
      <string>PAO</string>
      <string>Q185</string>
    </destinationSymbols>
  </HighwayRoutingData>
</ArrayOfHighwayRoutingData>
```

Comment: What does the rendered HTML look like with the delete hyperlinks? There is some erroneous HTML markup there where you close the table row then the table cell before another closing table row tag... it looks peculiar after `foreach($routingPoints->xpath(".//destinationSymbols//string") as $symbol){`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius https://codepen.io/dsflyerds/pen/XWezNjX

Comment: OK - so I see that you have fundamentally altered the layout of the table by adding new rows so my comment above about erroneous markup should be ignored.

Comment: Having just parsed your table through the [W3C Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) is becomes apparent that there is a mistake with the generated HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the structure of the XML file and the possibility that the same value of `string` could exist within several `HighwayRoutingData` nodes you need to positively identify the correct parent node from which to delete your selected `string` and to that end I'd suggest modifying your generated HTML slightly so that the `delete` hyperlink also contains the `tag` for that particular `HighwayRoutingData` node.

ie:

```
<a href="delete.php?action=delete&string='.$sym.'&tag='.$tag.'">Delete</a>
```

And then you can query the DOM to find that `tag` and from that point further query within that node to find the selected `string`

```
<?php
    /****************
        delete.php
        
        The hyperlink needs to have the Tag included so that the appropriate
        parent node in the XML can be targeted for the delete operation.
        
    */

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    session_start();


    if( isset(
        $_GET['action'],
        $_GET['string'],
        $_GET['tag'],
        $_SESSION['file']
    ) ){
        
        $file=$_SESSION['file'] ?: 'RouteSymbol.xml';
        
        
        if( $_GET['action']=='delete' ){
        
            libxml_use_internal_errors( true ) ;
            $dom=new DOMDocument();
            $dom->validateOnParse=false;
            $dom->recover=true;
            $dom->strictErrorChecking=false;
            $dom->load( $file );
            libxml_clear_errors();
            $xp=new DOMXPath( $dom );
            
            /*
                Find the appropriate parent node 
                based upon the given tag.
            */
            $root=$dom->getElementsByTagName('ArrayOfHighwayRoutingData')->item(0);
            $expr=sprintf( '//HighwayRoutingData/tag[ contains( text(), "%s") ]', urldecode( $_GET['tag'] ) );
            
            $col=$xp->query( $expr );
            if( $col && $col->length > 0 ){
                /*
                    now find the string node within the specified parent based 
                    upon string value using `contains(text(),"STRING")`
                */
                $dest=$xp->query( 'destinationSymbols', $col->item(0)->parentNode )->item(0);
                $expr=sprintf( 'string[ contains( text(), "%s" ) ]', urldecode( $_GET['string'] ) );
                
                $string=$xp->query( $expr, $dest )->item(0);
                if( $dest && $string ) $dest->removeChild( $string );
            }
            
            $dom->save( urldecode( $file ) );
        }
        
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
*<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument; 
$doc->load('theFile.xml');

$thedocument = $doc->documentElement;

//this gives you a list of the messages
$list = $thedocument->getElementsByTagName('message');

//figure out which ones you want -- assign it to a variable (ie: $nodeToRemove )
$nodeToRemove = null;
foreach ($list as $domElement){
  $attrValue = $domElement->getAttribute('time');
  if ($attrValue == 'VALUEYOUCAREABOUT') {
    $nodeToRemove = $domElement; //will only remember last one- but this is just an example :)
  }*
```

}

```
*//Now remove it.
if ($nodeToRemove != null)
$thedocument->removeChild($nodeToRemove);

echo $doc->saveXML();*
```

?>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).